# Filter objects which has no specific record met on its relational model

Tags: django, django-orm

Supposed i have this model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=25)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    is_present = models.BooleanField()
```

This is my implementation:

```
Employee.objects.bulk_create([
    Employee(name='Greg'),
    Employee(name='John'),
    Employee(name='Lesley'),
])

emp1 = Employee.objects.get(name='Greg')
emp1.attendance_set.create(is_present=True)
emp1.attendance_set.create(is_present=True)
emp1.attendance_set.create(is_present=True)

emp2 = Employee.objects.get(name='John')
emp2.attendance_set.create(is_present=True)
emp2.attendance_set.create(is_present=True)
emp2.attendance_set.create(is_present=True)

emp3 = Employee.objects.get(name='Lesley')
emp3.attendance_set.create(is_present=True)
emp3.attendance_set.create(is_present=False)
```

Now how can i filter employees from Employee level which has no `Attendance.is_present=False` That will yield the distinct record of Greg and John?

I tried this so far but it includes `Lesley`.

```
Employee.objects.filter(attendance__is_present=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to filter the right queryset using [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)

First if you have some desired criteria of your query that needs to be include to the queryset you can do a `filter()` function, then do the exclude() function that will remove all Employee object who has record `attendance__is_present=False`

```
Employee.objects.filter(
    # some criteria..
).exclude(
    attendance__is_present=False
).distinct()
```

If there is no criteria apart from `attendance__is_present=False` you can do directly as what *@Piyush S. Wanare* answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Attendance.objects.filter(is_present=True)
```

Comment: this will filter the Attendance instances not Employee

Comment: You can access the employee through `attendance.employee`

Comment: would it be possible if we filter from Employee level? i tried this `Employee.objects.filter(attendance__is_present=True)` but it include `Lesley`

Comment: Lesley has an attendance record whith `is_present=True`, I think what u want is to filter only the employees that have always attended. am I wrong?

Comment: but that's a different story

Comment: I think that this should do the trick `Employee.objects.filter(attendance__is_present=True).distinct()`

Comment: i tried that but Lesly has is_present=True so the filter will include her

Comment: i got the write solution Employee.objects.filter(attendance__is_present=True).exclude(attendance__is_present=False).distinc‌​t()

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do this:

```
Employee.objects.exclude(
    attendance__is_present=False
).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work -

```
employees = [attendance.employee for attendance in Attendance.objects.filter(is_present = False)]
```

Comment: Good one, just replace the `is_present = False` for `is_present = True` as the question says

Comment: it is impossible to filter from Employee? something like Employee.objects.filter(attendance__is_present=True)?